# How to read a user created Configuration file in C# [not web.config]

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, config

This is my current solution structure

```
Solution ABC

ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectWeb
    AppData --> CMS --> Configurations -->oneABC.config
    Areas -->Produts --> Web --> abc.cs [where I need to access that config]
    Web.config
ProjectC
```

PFB oneABC.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<oneABC xmlns:config="urn:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:configuration:type" config:version="12.2.7239.0">
    <countrycredentials>
        <add name="abbpoland" password="d0da0956b411" view="True" code="PL" />
        <add name="abbitaly" password="25430aa9fa22"  view="True" code="IT" />
    </countrycredentials>   
</oneAbbExternalDistributorInventoryConfig>
```

its not part of web.config  and the value inside oneABC.config are not static as we can have multiple add or single add as well.

Right now i need to fetch the details from this config file and use it to do some operations, I have done some digging to fetch these details but found none related to my problem.

PFB the function that i have written inside abc.cs to fetch the details:

```
//in culture im getting lang like 'en' ,'pl' or 'it' as per the url 
public static bool GetConfigurationValue(string culture)
        {
            string lang = culture;// im storing that language 
            
            ExeConfigurationFileMap customConfigFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            
            // in below i need to mention the path of config file right now its not working as its checking this file from C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\OneABC.Config

            customConfigFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "OneABC.Config";

            Configuration customConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(customConfigFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            AppSettingsSection appSettings = (customConfig.GetSection("countrycredentials") as AppSettingsSection);
            
            // below i need to save those tag value in such a way that if lang = PL then ill use view as true and return true 
            //and if ill get it in lang then ill use view as false and return false
           
        }
```

is there any universal way to set the file path of this file since currently im checking this in local and the ill need to deploy it to some server so file path will change.

Comment: The default location of any file in c# is the same folder that the c# executable is running.  So file location can be the same folder as c# executable of a relative path to the c# application or use an environmental variable to get the folder.

Comment: i have used this to fetch the path string a = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AppData/CMS/Configuration/oneABC.config")

Comment: Does the user have an account on the server?